# How do I limit REDIS memory usage with Sidekiq over time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I am using SideKiq with Heroku Redis on a Rails 5 app. Over time, my memory utilization has grown linearly, causing me to have to upgrade my plan every month or so. My load has been relatively flat.

I have an Eviction Policy of `noeviction`, as recommended in the SideKiq wiki. Does that mean that my memory footprint will continue to grow unabated over time?

Answer (score 3):

You should have 2 Redis instances running, one for Caching and another dedicated to Sidekiq.

Here's an entry from the Sidekiq wiki explaining this:

> Many people use Redis as a cache (it works great as a Rails cache store) but it's important that Sidekiq be run against a Redis instance that is not configured as a cache but as a persistent store. I recommend using two separate Redis instances, each configured appropriately, if you wish to use Redis for caching and Sidekiq. Redis namespaces do not allow for this configuration and come with many other problems, so using discrete Redis instances is always preferred.

That way, the cache store Redis will be able to manage evictions and memory as needed, whilst the Sidekiq Redis will be able to keep jobs persistently without a risk of an eviction. As you said the Sidekiq Redis instance should have `noeviction` set.

Just a guess, but likely the reason you had a linear increase in memory is because in other places of your Rails app you'd use Redis and that data would not be cleared due to the eviction policy, perhaps this was even Rails under the hood doing this, although I believe Rails would set a TTL everywhere, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score -1):

`noeviction` is a eviction policy setting in Redis. It results in Redis returning errors if the maximal memory usage is reached.
 To limit the memory usage in Redis you can set in the `redis.conf` file and set the `maxmemory` setting.
 [Read here](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache#maxmemory-configuration-directive) for more information about it.

Comment: But from SideKiq:

Redis runs best when all data fits in memory. Many people use Redis as a cache but it's important that Sidekiq be run against a Redis instance that is not configured as a cache but as a persistent store. You should set maxmemory-policy noeviction in redis.conf so Redis doesn't drop Sidekiq's data silently. I recommend using two separate Redis instances, each configured appropriately, if you wish to use Redis for caching and Sidekiq.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis

So, is it safe to run with a maxmemory, or will I lose active jobs?

Comment: You can read more about Redis persistence [here](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html).